# amcharts multiple series and datasets

Tags: dataset, series, amcharts

I'm trying to create a datetime based line chart, with a column series.

The problem I found is that amcharts defines dataProvider in chart level, not in series level.

My data points are like:

```
{date: '2015-11-04 10:12', value: 100}
```

Obviously I've configered `dataDateFormat` property.

And I want to add a column, that is **only** date based. i.e., it displays a number per day.  But amcharts force all points to be in the same dataset, isn't it possible to create another dataset, or to define the points in [x,y] method ? rather than all the values in one structure.

Comment: No, I'm afraid. There's no way to supply separate data providers for individual graphs.

Comment: So, column and line in the same chart, which have values with different [x,y] values (but still same axes), would be impossible? So sad, that the way the amcharts ask the data is so limiting.

Comment: Well you can have some sort of custom pre-processor script that "combines" separate series into one array. Shouldn't be too complicated.